# Django-fluent: How to integrate third-party apps?

Tags: python, django

Good evening!

I have just configured **[django-fluent](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-pages)** locally on my machine - it works as expected. Now I would like to add the django app **[django-envelope](https://django-envelope.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)**. I have been tying to follow the django-envelope instructions in the "Usage" section, and added this to my django-fluent installation:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
    url(r'^contact/',    include('envelope.urls')),
    #...
)
```

to the following path: **django-fluent.org/src/urls.py**. 
I also added:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load envelope_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% render_contact_form %}
{% endblock %}
```

to **django-fluent.org/src/frontend/templates/envelope/contact.html**

When visiting 127.0.0.1:8000/contact I still just get:

```
Page not found (404) - No published 'UrlNode' found for the path '/contact', language 'en'.
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you post envelope.urls?  Have you imported envelope into urls.py?

Comment: I tried to import the envelope views in the **urls.py** like this: `from envelope.views import ContactView`, while changing the url to:
`url(r'^contact/', ContactView.as_view()),` Still nada!

Comment: Turn on debug in settings.  Then you will get an error message showing all the valid urls.  That might help